# Hoisting of "var" in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have read the following

> Hoisting of var
>
> Hoisting is a JavaScript mechanism where variables and function
> declarations are moved to the top of their scope before code
> execution. This means that if we do this:
>
> ```
> console.log (greeter);
> var greeter = "say hello"
> ```
>
> it is interpreted as this:
>
> ```
> var greeter;
> console.log(greeter); // greeter is undefined
> greeter = "say hello"
> ```
>
> So var variables are hoisted to the top of their scope and initialized
> with a value of undefined.

But what happens with this (undefined)
They move at the top then why it is "undefined"?

```
if (true) {
  console.log(hi)
}
var hi = 1
```

If they are pushed up, they would also have to be "read" first, wouldn't they?

Comment: the same thing. the condition block "inherits" its outer block

Comment: "They move at the top then why it is "undefined","  because your variable is only getting its value after your if block

Comment: 1. Please source your quotes, _where_ did you read that? 2. _Did_ you read that? It explains that only the definition is hoisted and the variable is initialised to undefined.

Answer (score 0):

[Javascript only hoists declarations. The initialization is not hoisted.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#variable_hoisting). The assignment only happens after your `if` condition.

This is also why some JS developers prefer `let` over `var`. If you use `let`, you will get a very clear error saying the variable cannot be

```
if (true) {
  console.log(hi);
}
let hi = 1;
//Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'hi' before initialization
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration is hoisted, but the assignment isn't.

It's really the same as the second example in your quote.  So it's the equivalent of:

```
var hi;
if (true) {
  console.log(hi)
}
hi = 1
```

So `hi` is still undefined at the log statement.

This article has some good discussion and examples: https://blog.logrocket.com/demystifying-function-and-variable-hoisting-in-javascript/